# Accounting for sampling effort of independent variables in a regression analysis

Tags: regression, biostatistics, weights, measurement, offset

I would like the test whether the frequency of a cellular structure on a histology section is associated with (binary) patient outcomes. This would be a simple logistic regression of i.e. `glm(outcome ~ structure_frequency)`. However, the size of the histology sections vary between patients, and I want to properly account for this difference in sampling effort (more structures will be counted on larger sections).

Offsets are used to account for sampling effort in the *dependent* variable, but how can I achieve a similar effect for *independent* variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the size of the histology sections vary between patients, and I want to properly account for this difference in sampling effort (more structures will be counted on larger sections)

The issue here is that the *precision* of a value for your `structure_frequency` predictor could depend on the area of the histological section examined. A standard way to deal with that is to specify weights for the observations that are inversely related to the estimated variances of the predictor observations. If your `structure_frequency` is based on some type of repeatedly measured Bernoulli-distributed variable like the fraction of cells showing some particular structure, then the variance of an estimated fraction $\hat p$ could be estimated by $\hat p(1-\hat p)/n$, where $n$ is the number of cells examined.

Be very, very careful before you do that, however. For one, the observations from which you calculate `structure_frequency` might not be independently distributed across the sections, as assumed above. For another, it might be that the size of the section is itself an outcome predictor. For example, you might have much larger sections available from late-stage tumors than from a early-stage tumors. In that case you might be overweighting the late-stage cases if you try to account for the imprecision of `structure_frequency` estimates this way.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'll have to explore, both conceptually and analytically, the relationship between the variance of my counts and different outcomes/variables. I am always struck by the fact that when I read about weights, they seem very useful, but every authors says to be very careful with them, which has always made me reluctant to even explore using them.